# How to prove something like $\mathopen\mid{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2)\mathclose\mid=6$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Doing this by trying all possible cases is not hard for a group like this but I've been wondering if there is a more systematic method, applicable to groups of higher order, that doesn't rely on visualising the "symmetries" of the group. In general, finding the symmetries of an object seems to me to be hard to formalise and to require just trying a number of possibilities.

Comment: In general this is somewhat non-trivial. But, please check your argument! Last time I counted $\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ had six automorphisms! All the $3!=6$ permutations of the non-zero elements are actually automorphisms here.

Comment: Oh dear. Thank you, Jyrki. Turns out I hadn't thought enough about it.

Comment: If you are interested in the automorphism group of the direct product of a finite number of groups of order 2, note that an automorphism of such a product is an automorphism of a vector space over the field with 2 elements and use linear algebra.

Comment: Computing the automorphism group of a finite group $G$ is thought to be difficult. It is not hard to show that this can be done in time  $O(|G|^{\log_2 |G|})$ and there are no known better complexity results, although of course there are plenty of heuristics for specific cases.

Comment: $$\left|\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p)\right|=|\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)| = (p^2-1)(p^2-p).$$

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$In general, this is not an easy problem.

In your particular case you may note that if $a, b, c$ are the three non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ (I am using additive notation),then \begin{equation*}a + a = b + b = c + c = 0,\end{equation*}
the group is commutative, and \begin{equation*}a + b = c, b + c = a, c + a = b.\end{equation*}
To see the latter, just note that $a + b \ne 0$ (as $a \ne b$), and $a + b \ne a, b$ (as $a, b \ne 0$).

Then all permutations of $a, b, c$ yield an automorphism, so $\Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong S_{3}$.